# Cron Job to run every minute from 8am to 4.30pm in Cloudwatch Events

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a working CRON that currently executes from 8am to 5pm, I am having trouble changing this to finish at 4.30pm

Does CRON not support half hour specific time intervals?

Here is my current CRON setting

`0/1 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create hourly timespans to half-hour specific intervals as you guessed. If you really had the need, you could create a statement with all the specific times you want to run each day like with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661809/run-cron-every-5-minutes-in-specific-time-span). I doubt that makes sense for you though since you run it every minute.

Your included CRON command is not formatted correctly and will not work. It looks like you did not include the seconds. I am guessing your statement is something like:

```
0 0/1 8-17 ? * MON-FRI

At second :00, every minute starting at minute :00, 
every hour between 08am and 17pm, 
every day between Monday and Friday, every month
```

You can check CRON syntax with an explanation at:[Cron Expression Generator & Explainer](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html).